# 6 level cascading dropdown list using JSON array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON array with multiple objects that I want to incorporate with my drop-down list. Is it possible to create a 6-level cascading drop-down list which are dependent with each other? When the user choose a model, the different car models will populate the second dropdown list then the user will choose the car model and then the third to sixth dropdown list will then be populated by their respective year, color, price and transmission. I am new to javascript any help will be appreciated

```js
 var json = [{
      "Model": "BMW",
      "Car_Model": "6-series Gran Turismo",
      "Year": "2018",
      "Color": "Orange",
      "Price": "$71,195",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "Model": "BMW",
      "Car_Model": "i8",
      "Year": "2019",
      "Color": "Black",
      "Price": "$148,495",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "Model": "BMW",
      "Car_Model": "M5",
      "Year": "2017",
      "Color": "Blue",
      "Price": "$103,595",
   "Transmission": "Automatic"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Toyota",
      "Car_Model": "Sedan",
      "Year": "2017",
      "Color": "White",
      "Price": "$102,510",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Toyota",
      "Car_Model": "Camry",
      "Year": "2015",
      "Color": "Red",
      "Price": "$122,810",
   "Transmission": "Automatic"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Toyota",
      "Car_Model": "Corolla",
      "Year": "2016",
      "Color": "Blue",
      "Price": "$152,870",
   "Transmission": "Automatic"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Toyota",
      "Car_Model": "Hilux",
      "Year": "2018",
      "Color": "Black",
      "Price": "$258,695",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Toyota",
      "Car_Model": "Vios",
      "Year": "2019",
      "Color": "Blue",
      "Price": "$198,615",
   "Transmission": "Automatic"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Hyundai",
      "Car_Model": "Elantra",
      "Year": "2017",
      "Color": "Black",
      "Price": "$152,590",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Hyundai",
      "Car_Model": "Tucson",
      "Year": "2018",
      "Color": "Red",
      "Price": "$132,690",
   "Transmission": "Automatic"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Honda",
      "Car_Model": "Civic",
      "Year": "2016",
      "Color": "Blue",
      "Price": "$171,395",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Honda",
      "Car_Model": "Accord",
      "Year": "2019",
      "Color": "Black",
      "Price": "$159,445",
   "Transmission": "Automatic"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Honda",
      "Car_Model": "CR-V",
      "Year": "2017",
      "Color": "White",
      "Price": "$193,675",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    }
  ];
```

So far, this is what I have

```js
var addOptionList = {
    A: ["6-series Gran Turismo", "i8", "M5"],
    B: ["Sedan", "Camry", "Corolla", "Hilux", "Vios"],
 C: ["Elantra", "Tucson"],
    D: ["Civic", "Accord", "CR-V"],
    
}

    function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("car_model").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (categoryId in addOptionList[value]) {
                catOptions += "<option>" + addOptionList[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("car_model").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    }
```

```html
<b>MODEL:</b>
      <select id="model" name="model" onchange="changecat(this.value);" >
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Model...</option>
          <option value="A"> BMW </option>
          <option value="B"> Toyota </option>
          <option value="C"> Hyundai </option>
          <option value="D"> Honda </option>
        </select>
      </select>
<b>CAR MODEL:</b>     
      <select ID="car_model" NAME="car_model">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Model First...</option>
   </select>
<b>YEAR:</b>    
     <select ID="year" NAME="year">
     </select> 
<b>COLOR:</b>           
     <select id = "color" name = "color">
     </select>
<b>PRICE:</b> 
     <select id = "price" name = "price">
     </select>
<b>TRANSMISSION:</b>           
     <select id = "trnasmission" name = "transmission">
     </select>
```

Comment: Can you post your attempt, HTML, and expected output?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Post updated. Please see @JackBashford

Comment: Post updated. Please see @FrankerZ

Answer (score 0):

Did i understand you right? if you selected one of those choices from the Model the following select box will also change depends on the json array data?

If yes check these lines of code:

```js
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    for(i=0;i<json.length;i++){
       $("#Model").append("<option value="+ json[i]["Model"] +">"+ json[i]["Model"] +"</option>");
       $("#Car_Model").append("<option value="+ json[i]["Model"] +">"+ json[i]["Car_Model"] +"</option>");
       $("#Year").append("<option value="+ json[i]["Model"] +">"+ json[i]["Year"] +"</option>");
       $("#Color").append("<option value="+ json[i]["Model"] +">"+ json[i]["Color"] +"</option>");
       $("#Price").append("<option value="+ json[i]["Model"] +">"+ json[i]["Price"] +"</option>");
       $("#Transmission").append("<option value="+ json[i]["Model"] +">"+ json[i]["Transmission"] +"</option>");
    }
  })
  

  $("#Model").change(function(){
      $("#Car_Model")[0].selectedIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex
       $("#Year")[0].selectedIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex
       $("#Color")[0].selectedIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex
       $("#Price")[0].selectedIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex
       $("#Transmission")[0].selectedIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Model"></select>
<select id="Car_Model"></select>
<select id="Year"></select>
<select id="Color"></select>
<select id="Price"></select>
<select id="Transmission"></select>
<script>
 var json = [{
      "Model": "BMW",
      "Car_Model": "6-series Gran Turismo",
      "Year": "2018",
      "Color": "Orange",
      "Price": "$71,195",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "Model": "BMW",
      "Car_Model": "i8",
      "Year": "2019",
      "Color": "Black",
      "Price": "$148,495",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "Model": "BMW",
      "Car_Model": "M5",
      "Year": "2017",
      "Color": "Blue",
      "Price": "$103,595",
   "Transmission": "Automatic"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Toyota",
      "Car_Model": "Sedan",
      "Year": "2017",
      "Color": "White",
      "Price": "$102,510",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Toyota",
      "Car_Model": "Camry",
      "Year": "2015",
      "Color": "Red",
      "Price": "$122,810",
   "Transmission": "Automatic"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Toyota",
      "Car_Model": "Corolla",
      "Year": "2016",
      "Color": "Blue",
      "Price": "$152,870",
   "Transmission": "Automatic"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Toyota",
      "Car_Model": "Hilux",
      "Year": "2018",
      "Color": "Black",
      "Price": "$258,695",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Toyota",
      "Car_Model": "Vios",
      "Year": "2019",
      "Color": "Blue",
      "Price": "$198,615",
   "Transmission": "Automatic"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Hyundai",
      "Car_Model": "Elantra",
      "Year": "2017",
      "Color": "Black",
      "Price": "$152,590",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Hyundai",
      "Car_Model": "Tucson",
      "Year": "2018",
      "Color": "Red",
      "Price": "$132,690",
   "Transmission": "Automatic"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Honda",
      "Car_Model": "Civic",
      "Year": "2016",
      "Color": "Blue",
      "Price": "$171,395",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Honda",
      "Car_Model": "Accord",
      "Year": "2019",
      "Color": "Black",
      "Price": "$159,445",
   "Transmission": "Automatic"
    },
    {
      "Model": "Honda",
      "Car_Model": "CR-V",
      "Year": "2017",
      "Color": "White",
      "Price": "$193,675",
   "Transmission": "Manual"
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Comment: The author of this question didn't provide an HTML sample, just improve the filtering thanks.

Comment: Yes, but as for the 1st and 2nd drop-down list, it should only have one of the choices and not in multiple forms

Comment: So if it's not multiple, so why you still want to use select element?

Comment: Please see the posted html above on how the 1st and the 2nd dropdown list should work